# Determining cycle time and and hold time in logic circuits

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computer-architecture, logic

First I have general question. In a circuit with both logic and D edge flip flop does hold time have to satisfy $t_{hold} < t_{setup}($D-FF$) + t_{pd-min}$(Logic),

or is it enough that $t_{hold} \le t_{setup}($D-FF$) + t_{pd-min}$(Logic) ?

Also i have a question about a specific circuit: [image]

with the following times: [image]

the question is how much time at least, before and after the fall of the clock does the Input have to be steady? when it is given that $t_{hold}=8ns$

Now, from what I know, the input has to be kept steady for at least $t < t_{pd-min}$(Logic) +$t_{setup}$ time. So I don't understand how $t_{hold}$ comes into consideration here. I'll be glad if could explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if someone is interested I have solved the question myself.

First of all, it indeed is possible that $t_{hold} = t_{setup} + t_{pd-min}$.

And about the input time, it has to satisfy: $$t_{hold} \le t_{pd-min}(logic) + t_{input-valid-min}$$

since $t_{hold} = 8ns$ and $t_{pd-min}(Logic) = 10ns$ , even $t_{input-valid-min} = 0$ satisfies this.